# Order a query with two keys SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to order a query by two keys. The query is built with several subqueries. The table contains, beside columns with other data, two columns, Key and Key_Father. So I need to order the results since SQL to print the results in a report. This is an example:

Key     Key_Father
4          NULL
1          4
2          4
7          NULL
1          7
2          7

As you can see is a structure father-son, where a row is a father if the Key_Father is NULL and the Key column start from one for each son with a different father.
The first subquery gives the data in order, because is stored on that order in the table, but the second subquery that uses a group by, no. So I tried adding a extra column with Row_Number on the first subquery to keep that order, but the second subquery does the same thing.

This is the query:

```
SELECT Orden,INV_Key,Key_Padre,INV.INV_ID,INV.BOD_Bodega_ID,
CASE WHEN MAX(HIS_Ventas) > 0 OR max(HIS_Disponible) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Participacion,MAX(ISNULL(HIS_Ventas,0)) AS Ventas
FROM(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C.INV_Compra_ID) Orden,C.BOD_Bodega_ID,INV_Key,Key_Padre,CD.INV_ID
FROM dbo.INV_COMPRAS_USADOS C
INNER JOIN dbo.INV_COMPRAS_USADOS_DET CD ON C.INV_Compra_ID = CD.INV_Compra_ID
WHERE C.INV_Compra_ID = @Compra_ID
AND ((Key_Padre IS NULL AND CD.INV_Catalogo_Codigo = ISNULL(@Cod_Catalogo,CD.INV_Catalogo_Codigo)
AND INV_Key IN (SELECT DISTINCT Key_Padre
FROM dbo.INV_COMPRAS_USADOS_DET
WHERE INV_Compra_ID = @Compra_ID AND Key_Padre IS NOT NULL))
OR Key_Padre IN (SELECT DISTINCT INV_Key
FROM dbo.INV_COMPRAS_USADOS_DET
WHERE INV_Compra_ID = @Compra_ID AND (Key_Padre IS NULL AND CD.INV_Catalogo_Codigo = ISNULL(@Cod_Catalogo,CD.INV_Catalogo_Codigo))))) INV
LEFT JOIN DBO.HIS_HISTORICO_DETALLE HD ON INV.INV_ID = HD.INV_ID AND HD.BOD_Bodega_ID = INV.BOD_Bodega_ID
LEFT JOIN DBO.HIS_HISTORICO_INVENTARIO H on H.HIS_Historico_ID= HD.HIS_Historico_ID AND (CONVERT(datetime,(convert(varchar(20),HIS_Historico_Ano) + '/' + convert(varchar(20),HIS_Historico_Mes) + '/01')) BETWEEN @FechaDesde AND @FechaHasta)
WHERE H.HIS_Historico_Mes IS NOT NULL OR INV.INV_ID IS NULL
GROUP BY Orden,INV_Key,Key_Padre,INV.INV_ID,INV.BOD_Bodega_ID,HIS_Historico_Ano,HIS_Historico_Mes
```

Another interesting thing (well for me) is that when I change the @Variables for Constant values, the second query keeps the correct order, even when the constant values are the same that the @variables. This is just a portion of the total query, is a subquery that needs of another two selects, and I need to keep the order from those selects too.

So I hope that someone could help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To order the results you need to place an `ORDER BY` clause on the *outermost* `SELECT` statement.  Using `ORDER BY` in a nested `SELECT` is generally not permitted but even if you work around it (e.g. by using `TOP`), you can't rely on the results being ordered in any particular way.

Without an `ORDER BY` the results may appear to be coming out in the order you want but this cannot be relied upon.  Running the same query on a different server or at some point in the future may produce a different order where differences in statistics, server load, etc can affect how the query optimizer actually executes the statement.

The portion of the query you've provided is outputting the following columns.  Which are the ones you want to order by?

```
Orden (although this is just an alias for INV_Compra_ID as far as orderin is concerned)
INV_Key
Key_Padre
INV_ID
BOD_Bodega_ID
Participacion
Ventas
```

Let's say you want to order by just thre of them, then you need to append the following clause to the outermost `SELECT`:

```
ORDER BY
    Orden,
    INV_Key,
    Key_Padre,
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. I'm not sure if I'm missing an obvious simplification though.

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(Key_Father,[Key]), ISNULL(Key_Father,-1),[Key]
```